# I placed a function into my .Rprofile file, but it doesn't appear when I load R? I don't understand why

Tags: r

My .Rprofile file looks like this:

```
# Will be run at the start of an R sesssion
# -----------------------------------------
.First <- function(){
    # Set the default CRAN
    CRAN <- "http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/"
    # Load standard libraries
    library(Hmisc)




    # My functions
    # ------------
    # R version of lookfor: `names(data)[grep('pattern',names(data))]`

    lkf <- function(d,p) names(d)[grep(p,names(d))]
    cat("\nWelcome at", date(), "\n")

}

# Will be run at the end of an R sesssion
# -----------------------------------------

.Last <- function(){
     cat("\nGoodbye at ", date(), "\n")
}
```

I use the `lkf` function to quickly look for variables in a particular dataframe. It's modelled on the Stata `lookfor` function. However, it isn't available to me when I start R.

e.g.

```
> ls()
[1] "fresh_install"
> mydata <- data.frame(id = c(1:10))
> ls()
[1] "fresh_install" "mydata"
> lkf(mydata,"id")
Error: could not find function "lkf"
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?Startup`,

> Next, if a function `.First` is found on the search path, it is executed as `.First()`

So as it is the case with any other function, `lkf` will be created in the function's environment which is destroyed as the function exits.

Instead, you could define `lkf` outside `.First`:

```
lkf <- function(d,p) grep(p, names(d), value = TRUE)

.First <- function() {
   [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you like to offer comment on whether R users recommend my approach? Do people typically have a few helper functions that they write, and then load when R starts?

Comment: @drstevok I would suggest rather building your own library and using it when needed.

Comment: Sure. Using a .Rprofile is pretty common practice. However it can hamper reproducible research if you plan to share your code: imagine sending us code that contains calls to `lkf`, we would not have easy access to its definition (.Rprofile is your personal and hidden file.) So .Rprofile is great for things **you only** plan to use, to make your life easier.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. That's sort of what I had heard, but am not sure how to go about this. Do you have any links or pointers? An example package perhaps?